# CodeIgniter HTML table generator with custom layout inside

Tags: html, codeigniter, html-table

CI `table->generate($data1, $data2, $data3)` will output my data in a form of **simple table** like:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>data1</td>
        <td>data2</td>
        <td>data3</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

What if I need a  **complex cell layout** with multiple `$vars` within each cell:

```
$data1 = array('one', 'two', 'three');
```

and I want something like this:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div class="caption">$data1[0]</div>
            <span class="span1">$data1[1] and here goes <strong>$data1[2]</strong></span>
        </td>
        <td>...</td>
        <td>...</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

How should I code that piece?

For now I just generate the content of `td` in a model and then call `generate()`. But this means that my HTML for the cell is in the model but I would like to keep it in views.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I would suggest is have a view that you pass the data that Generates the td structure. Capture the output of the view and pass this to the table generator. This keeps your structure in the view albeit a different one.

Comment: Great solution! Didn't know that you can load->view() into a variable!

Answer (score 0):

Hailwood's answer isn't the best way to do it.
the html table class has a data element on the [add_row](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/table.html#CI_Table::add_row) method.  so the code would be:

```
$row = array();
$row[] = array('data' => "<div class='caption'>{$data1[0]}</div><span class='span1'>{$data1[1]} and here goes <strong>{$data1[2]}</strong></span>");
$row[] = $col2;
$row[] = $col3;

$this->table->add_row($row)
echo $this->table->generate();
```

as an aside, having a class named caption in a table is semantically confusing because table has a caption tag.